# I want to add value into cart until it is not being removed by the user

Tags: jquery

### I want to store the value into cart but it is being clear when refresh the page.

```
   <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var itemCount = 0;
        $('.add-to-cart').click(function () {
            debugger;
            itemCount++;
            localStorage.setItem("ProductNumber", itemCount);
            var val = localStorage.getItem("ProductNumber");

            $('.bag').html(val).css('margin-top', '-14px');
            $('.bag').html(val).css('margin-left', '4px');
            $('.bag').html(val).css('display', 'block');
            $('.bag').html(val).css('color', 'white');

            //$('.bag').html(itemCount).css('margin-top', '-1px');
        });
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add initial value of ItemCount from localStorage

```
var itemCount = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProductNumber")) || 0;
```